# Can't open display: 192.168...

Tags: xorg, x-server

Recently I stumbled across the problem with remote X display (without `ssh`).

I have two hosts

- 192.168.0.3 - which runs xclients
- 192.168.0.4 - which has xserver

My configuration of lightdm.conf

```
#
# General configuration
#
[LightDM]
[SeatDefaults]
xserver-allow-tcp=true
greeter-session=unity-greeter
greeter-hide-users=true
user-session=default
session-wrapper=/etc/X11/Xsession
autologin-user=debian
autologin-user-timeout=0

[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true
```

On 192.168.0.104 I've executed `xhost +`.

I've also checked with telnet if port 6000 is open for connection by executing 
`telnet 192.168.0.104 6000`

telnet successfully connected to remote computer.

But when I am trying to display something on remote X by command:

`xeyes -display 192.168.0.104`

I got:
`Error: Can't open display`

both machines have Debian installed with lxde.

Any suggestions why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the display to connect to on the remote machine, e.g.:

```
xeyes -display 192.168.0.104:0
```

In general, a display name is:

```
hostname:displaynumber.screennumber
```

`hostname` can be omitted for local connections, and `.screennumber` can be omitted to use the default screen.